# Sumar entero doble a una fecha

Tags: laravel, datetime, laravel-livewire

tengo que hacer una recepción de una reparación, por ende completo un formulario donde me pide Fecha y hora  que voy a iniciar reparación y el estimado que es un input tipo number, es decir pueden ser 4 u 4.5 horas y quiero obtener una fecha final de reparacion y una hora final

Este sería mi formulario:

```
            <div class="form-group col-span-6 sm:col-6 grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 gap-5">
                <div class="mx-2"  > 
                    <x-jet-label for="solicitud.fecha_ini" value="{{ __('Fecha Turno:') }}" />
                    <input type="text" id="fecha_ini" class="form-control flatpickr" data-toggle="date" wire:model="solicitud.fecha_ini" required placeholder="Seleccione fecha">
                    <x-jet-input-error for="solicitud.fecha_ini" class="mt-2" />                
                </div> 
                <div class="mx-2">
                    <x-jet-label for="solicitud.hora_ini" value="{{ __('Hora Asignada') }}" />
                    <input type="text"  class="form-control flatpickrh" data-toggle="date" wire:model.defer="solicitud.hora_ini" required placeholder="Seleccione hora">
                    <x-jet-input-error for="solicitud.hora_ini" class="mt-2" />
                </div>
                <div class="mx-2">
                    <x-jet-label for="estimado" value="{{ __('Tiempo Estimado') }}" />
                    <input type="number" step="0.5" class="form-control"  wire:model.defer="estimado"  >
                    <x-jet-input-error for="estimado" class="mt-2" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

acá recibo mis datos

```
        $fecha=date_create($this->solicitud->fecha_ini);
        $fecha=date_format($fecha,"Y-m-d");
        $fechaFin=$fecha;
        $horaFin
```

Sipo por ejemplo la fecha y hora de inicio don 20-12-2022 14:00 y estimado son 4.5 horas
quiero obtener:
Fecha fin: 20-12-2022
hora Fin 18:30
he buscado y no encuentro nada parecido

Comment: el estimado simpre será fracion de media hora 4.5m 5 m 5.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colocar 4.5 horas es super complicado pues eso los humanos lo entienden como 4 horas y media o 4 horas y 30 minutos pero y las maquinas como harían entonces?

Yo te aconsejo que uses horas y minutos y, o lo haces en dos inputs o, cuando pidas lo divides pero lo veo igual muy complicado. Luego puedes usar esta función.

ojo en el ejemplo que lo puse así para corroborar que en efecto suma el día, osea le sumo 23 horas y pasa de "hoy" a mañana.

```
<?php
    // Define timezone
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
    // $dateStart = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $dateStart = date('2022-12-20 14:00');
    $hours = 23;
    $minutes = 30;
    $newDate = strtotime ( "+$hours hour" , strtotime ($dateStart) ) ;
    $newDate = strtotime ( "+$minutes minute" , $newDate ) ;
    $newDate = strtotime ( "+0 second" , $newDate ) ;
    $newDate = date ( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' , $newDate);
    echo $newDate; // 2022-12-21 13:30:00
?>
```

Comment: Gracias,  @OCHOA, es lo que necesitaba